# How to interpret the coefficients of nested ERGM models?

Tags: social-networking

I am trying to explain an homophily effect that I observe in a friendship network, through other homophily effects, and I was wondering whether nested models could do this.

Here is the thing. I'm working on a friendship network of middle-school students. With the 'nodematch' ergm term, it is very clear that students with the same social background (parents' socio-economic status, actually) have higher probabilities of forming a tie. This could be partly explained by the fact that, in their town, students' from a same social background generally live closer to one another. So I add a second 'nodematch' term in my model, which counts the number of edges for which both students are from the same neighborhood. It is indeed significant (the 'anova.ergm' function also confirms that this second model is better than the first one) ; and in this second model, **the coefficient of the social homophily parameter is still significant, but smaller than in model 1**. Can I interpret this as spatial proximity "explaining" part of the social homophily effect (as you would for nested linear regressions) ? Or are the coefficients in the two models not comparable ?

Here is a short example from statnet's sampson data which looks much like my own case :

```
# Load statnet and the data :
library(statnet)
library(stargazer)
data('sampson')

# Estimate 2 models : one only with homophily on 'cloisterville', and one with both 'cloisterville' and 'group' homophily.
m1 <- ergm(samplike ~ edges + nodematch('cloisterville'))
m2 <- ergm(samplike ~ edges + nodematch('cloisterville') + nodematch('group'))

# The second model is a better fit than the first one :
anova.ergm(m1,m2)

# Look at the models :
stargazer(m1,m2,type="text")
# The log-odd of nodematch.cloisterville considerably fell down, from 1.585 to 0.586 !
# That's because most edges matching on cloisterville also match on groups.
# However, is it okay to consider that group homophily explains about two thirds of cloisterville homophily ? [(1.585 - 0.586)/1.585 = 0.63]
# Is there any way to assess the significance of this fall in the cloisterville coefficient ?
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Timothée

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the interpretation is the same. Particularly in the case you have supplied, which, since it does not initialize MCMC (containing no dyadic-dependent terms), is simply a logistic regression. In the case where you have dyadic-dependent terms, the point estimates for `ergm` are still derived from `glm`. The `ergm` magic is really related to the estimation of the *standard errors*.

This can be verified by using `glm` to estimate the model:

```
library(statnet)
library(stargazer)
data('sampson')

y <- gvectorize(as.matrix(samplike),  censor.as.na= T)
x1 <- 1*outer(samplike %v% "cloisterville",samplike %v% "cloisterville",FUN="==")
x1 <- gvectorize(x1)
x2 <- 1*outer(samplike %v% "group",samplike %v% "group",FUN="==")
x2 <- gvectorize(x2)
glm1 <- glm(y ~ 1 + x1, family = "binomial")
names(glm1$coefficients) <- c("edges", "nodematch.cloisterville")
glm2 <- glm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2, family = "binomial")
names(glm2$coefficients) <- c("edges", "nodematch.cloisterville", "nodematch.group")

stargazer(m1,glm1,m2,glm2,type="text")

=================================================================================
                                           Dependent variable:                   
                        ---------------------------------------------------------
                             samplike          y          samplike          y    
                        exponential family logistic  exponential family logistic 
                           random graph                 random graph             
                               (1)            (2)           (3)            (4)   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
edges                       -0.662***      -0.662***     -1.768***      -1.768***
                             (0.176)        (0.176)       (0.256)        (0.256) 

nodematch.cloisterville      -0.487*        -0.487*        -0.460        -0.460  
                             (0.254)        (0.254)       (0.304)        (0.304) 

nodematch.group                                           2.643***      2.643*** 
                                                          (0.304)        (0.304) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                                  306                          306   
Log Likelihood                             -181.749                     -137.282 
Akaike Inf. Crit.            367.497        367.497       280.565        280.565 
Bayesian Inf. Crit.          374.944                      291.736                
=================================================================================
Note:                                                 *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

In your original example, you can interpret it the homophily effect of neighborhood as net of the homophily effect of SES. Which seems to say: SES matters, neighborhood matters more. I'd imagine that those two variables are fairly highly correlated.

Comment: Thanks for that good explenation. I wonder, in this example its only  nodematch wich correspond in the outer function with FUN = "==" when I'm correct?! a nodefactor would translate in "*"?